# Can I export the data stored in datastore to an Excel?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to export my data in datastore to an Excel format file. The data is simple, just stringProperty. Can I do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

if the app is written in python you should read how to download data:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata

you can export the data to a csv file and then import that in excel.

edit:
there is a howto even for java apps:
http://ikaisays.com/2010/06/10/using-the-bulkloader-with-java-app-engine/